# How does publication of a society journal by a for-profit publisher work?

Tags: journals, publishers

I have observed that, sometimes, non-profit academic societies have journals.  Usually, the journal is published by the society, or by a partnership between societies.  But sometimes, the society's journal is published by a for-profit publisher.

How do these arrangements work?  What aspects of the journal are controlled by the society, and what aspects are controlled by the for-profit publisher?  I'm curious about both content and financial control.

Random examples:

- https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-of-the-european-ceramic-society/about/aims-and-scope
- https://ceramics.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/hub/journal/15512916/homepage/contact
- https://www.tandfonline.com/action/journalInformation?show=societyInformation&journalCode=tsta20

Comment: In the cases I am familiar with, everything prior to acceptance is in the learned society's control, and then production and post-production is the domain of the for-profit. Not an answer, as I'm not privy to the contractual negotiations that actually spell out the details.